# ansible - select multiple number of random names from list

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible 2.10 and have a variable with a list of 14 names.  From this list, I want to assign a random number (from 9-14) of names and write this to a text file.  I'm struggling with how to do this in ansible. So far,  have this:

```
in default.yml:
  randomNames: 'chad', 'bob', 'alice'.....

 - name: Define random number
   set_fact:
     numberNames:  "{{ range(9,14) }} | random }}"

 - name: Add random names to file
   lineinfile:
     src: {{ randomNames }}
     dest: namesList.txt
   loop:
      "{{ numberNames }}"
```

but I get an error "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list. I know this is isn't the correct way to do this, but can someone help me figure out what is the best way to do this?

I should add I also need the names, one per line:

```
   bob
   alice
   ted
   ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems here. First, this isn't a list:

```
randomNames: 'chad', 'bob', 'alice'
```

That's just a string. If you want a list, write:

```
randomNames: [chad, bob, alice]
```

Or:

```
randomNames:
  - chad
  - bob
  - alice
```

(I've dropped the quotes, because they're not necessary, but you can write `'chad'` instead of `chad`, etc, if you prefer).

---

Second, this task...

```
- name: Define random number
  set_fact:
    numberNames:  "{{ range(9,14) }} | random }}"
```

...does not produce a list; it returns a single number. So in the subsequent task, when you write:

```
- name: Add random names to file
  lineinfile:
    src: {{ randomNames }}
    dest: namesList.txt
  loop: "{{ numberNames }}"
```

You're trying to loop over something like the value `10`.

---

Lastly, the `lineinfile` module doesn't have a `src` parameter.

If your goal is to write `N` random names to a file, you might want
the [`shuffle`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#shuffling-a-list) filter, which randomizes a list:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    "randomNames": [
      "Bob", "Alice", "James", "Robert", "John", "Michael", "David", "William", "Richard",
      "Joseph", "Thomas", "Charles", "Christopher", "Daniel", "Matthew", "Anthony", "Mark",
      "Donald", "Steven", "Paul", "Andrew", "Joshua", "Mary", "Patricia", "Jennifer",
      "Linda", "Elizabeth", "Barbara", "Susan", "Jessica", "Sarah", "Karen", "Lisa",
      "Nancy", "Betty", "Margaret", "Sandra", "Ashley", "Kimberly", "Emily", "Donna",
      "Michelle"]

  tasks:
    - name: Define random number
      set_fact:
        numberNames: "{{ range(9,14) | random }}"

    - name: Add a random name to a file
      lineinfile:
        path: namesList.txt
        line: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ (randomNames|shuffle)[:numberNames|int] }}"
```